# Enumerated types and Strings

Tags: java, string, enums

I want to have a string assigned to each enum so that when the `toString()` method is called on an enum it will return the string. I have tried the code below based on what I was able to find on my own but get an error:

> RecycleCode(String) is undefined.

How do I assign a string to an enum and then return it using the `toString()` method?

```
public enum RecycleCode {
    ONE("PET"), 
    TWO("HDPE"), 
    THREE("PVC"), 
    FOUR("LDPE"), 
    FIVE("PP"), 
    SIX("PS"), 
    SEVEN("OTHER"), 
    ABS("ABS");

    public String toString() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `ONE("PET")` does?

Comment: You need a non default constructor in your enum: `RecycleCode(String s)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a `String` in each of your enum declarations, but you don't have a constructor that accepts a `String`, or an instance variable to hold it.  Try

```
private String name;
private RecycleCode(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then you can reference the instance variable `name` in your `toString()` method.

```
    return name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum RecycleCode {
ONE("PET"),
TWO("HDPE"),
THREE("PVC"),
FOUR("LDPE"),
FIVE("PP"),
SIX("PS"),
SEVEN("OTHER"),
ABS("ABS");

private String name;

public RecycleCode(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}

public String toString(){

    return name;

    }
}
```

Comment: `return name()` should be `return name`

Comment: Yes, didn't looked at this :) Thanks.